# How can I have a Trash/Recycle Bin for my Samba shares?

Tags: debian, backup, samba, trash

I have a couple of Samba shares on my NAS running Debian Squeeze which I access through Windows 7. Deleting any of the files from Windows will completely delete the files from the NAS server.

Is there anyway to have a similar feature installed like the Trash/Recycle Bin? It would be nice if there even was a similar concept as <kbd>Delete</kbd>, file goes to trash and is deleted, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>, file is deleted and no keep copy is kept anywhere.

Is there such thing I could install?

Comment: Try this nice little tutorial on how to activate the bin for samba shares. http://timtrott.co.uk/enabling-recycle-bin-functionality-samba/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for the vfs_recycle module to Samba.

- [vfs_recycle - Samba VFS recycle bin | samba.org](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html)

In your `smb.conf` file for a given share:

```
[share]
Path = /data/share
vfs objects = recycle
recycle:repository = .recycle
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:versions = yes
```

Comment: Does this configuration supports the Shift+Delete feature to permanently delete the file as mentioned by the OP?

Comment: @m7913d not sure, hadn't tried it. I suspect it will.